# How to specify strategy for a single git push

Tags: git, git-push

I like to keep my default push strategy on `current` but every now and then I need to modify multiple branches and then push all of them i.e. I need to do a push with the strategy set to `matching`.

When done branch by branch it generates a lot of noise and takes time. The other option I have is to temporarily set my push strategy for that repository, do the push and then set it back to my default. This got me wondering is there a way to specify push strategy for a single push similar to the git merge strategies?

Note: I am aware of the push option `--all` but I also have local branches not meant to be pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "push strategy" you mean the setting of `push.default` (which goes with `current` and `matching`).

To run one Git command while overriding the configuration setting of some Git configuration variable(s) for the duration of that one command, use:

```
git -c <name>=<value> command
```

e.g., `git -c push.default=matching push`.

Note, however, that `push.default` affects *only* a `git push` that *does not* list refspecs on the command line.  For scripting purposes it's probably wiser, in general, to construct the set of refspecs that you *do* intend to push, then pass them as arguments:

```
pushargs=
for b in ...; do
    if want-to-push $b; then
        pushargs="$pushargs $b"
    fi
done
if [ -n "$pushargs" ]; then git push $remote $pushargs; fi
```

for instance (assuming `$remote` is already set and the `...` part has some obvious way to fill it in).  In addition, if you mean `matching`, the special refspec `:` means that:

```
git push origin :
```

for instance.

Comment: I did not realise that the question would generalise so well. And I could have asked "How to override a git configuration value for a single commit"